# Designing class for fixed-size data structure backed by ArrayList

Tags: design, java, api, api-design

Say we want to write a Java class that represents a fixed-size list. Let's call it `Chunk.java` (as in, it represents a chunk of data to be processed or sent somewhere). My implementation of this class can be outlined as follows:

1. A chunk is represented internally by an `ArrayList`.
2. It has a constructor that takes as argument an integer representing the capacity of a chunk, as in `public Chunk(int capacity)`.
3. For adding elements to the chunk, it provides two methods:

   - `void add(E element)`: Adds the specified element if and only there is room for it, otherwise throws an `IllegalStateException`.
   - `void addUnrestricted(E element)`: Adds the specified element *without* ensuring the capacity; it delegates capacity checking to a different public method called `hasRoom()` which the user of the API is expected to use if they choose to add elements using this method.

Now, this means there's two ways the API can be used; either by having the users do the capacity checking themselves with `hasRoom` and `addUnrestricted`, or having the class itself do the capacity checking and enforcing it with `add`. This means the API can technically be misused and a chunk can go over-capacity if `addUnrestricted` is used without  `hasRoom`, which brings me to the question:

Is this a sound design? Why or why not?

To be clear, I've thought about having a single `boolean add(E element)` method that just returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a given element can be added, and completely doing away with `hasRoom`. I am not sure if this would actually be the better design, though.

Comment: Why is there an `addUnrestricted` method? That's what doesn't make sense to me. What is the use case for adding an element without checking for capacity?

Comment: @GregBurghardt It's a good question. Originally, the method was not part of the class. However, when I used the API, I found myself calling hasRoom before adding elements to the list because the existing add method does not give any indication as to whether the current element can be added besides throwing an exception. Since hasRoom does the capacity checking, calling 'add right after it felt redundant to me because it *also* performs capacity checking.

Comment: "Is this a sound design? Why or why not?" - while it's sometimes useful to provide options within the same design for advanced users, usually it's better to focus on the 80% use case and narrow down your options. Generally, from usability point of view, it's better when there aren't several conceptually different ways to do the same thing.

Comment: "Since hasRoom does the capacity checking, calling 'add right after it felt redundant to me because it also performs capacity checking" - that sort of redundancy is completely fine. If you're concerned about performance, removing the double check is not going to have an effect *at all*. Program defensively and don't worry about microoptimizations that have no perceivable impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three thoughts immediately came to mind:

1. Checking the capacity before adding an element should execute very, very fast. Chunk should be more concerned about enforcing its own constraints rather than saving a few CPU clock cycles. Just live with consumers and Chunk both checking capacity before adding an element.
2. Since chunk is a fixed size, make it immutable by forcing consumers to pass in their own ArrayList of elements to the Chunk constructor, and creating a read-only copy of the elements.

   Capacity checks will be pointless, since the ArrayList cannot be modified after initializing a new Chunk.
3. Build on number two by adding mutator methods that return a `new Chunk` with a copy of the altered ArrayList. That way each individual instance of Chunk is both fixed size *and* immutable. Consumers have the option of altering the Chunk, but they must knowingly assign a reference to the altered chunk to a variable, so that the old Chunk can be discarded.

   Adding an element to a Chunk no longer requires consumers to check the size. In fact, the Chunk shouldn't need to check the size either, since each Chunk has a fixed size and presumably adding an element increases the size by one.

Comment: For my purposes, I think option #1 will suffice. Appreciate your input. Just going to keep the original add method and remove the other (unrestricted) one.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a sound design? Why or why not?

That depends largely on your goal for the `Chunk` class. Based on what you've described, we want the capacity to be invariant. But based on the current implementation, the capacity can change if the API is used in an unintended way. This opens the door to all kinds of bugs. E.g. I create a valid chunk in spot A, and use it safely in spot B under those assumptions. But if someone later changes A, then my assumptions in B may no longer be valid, and could silently break the application. **In general, try to make invalid states unrepresentable**.

If your primary concern is that the size check is done twice, don't worry about it. That's a small price to pay for the cost of potential bugs in the future. But if this really becomes a performance bottleneck (e.g. you've got a tight loop doing millions of iterations), and this duplicate check is truly an issue (you can use a profiler to determine this), then the `boolean add` method is definitely the way to go, since it replaces a check and an insert with a single atomic operation.

I see that you've tagged this as Java, but a common C# pattern is to provide two methods: `void doOp() throws SomeException` and `boolean tryDoOp()`, giving the developer the freedom to choose which is more appropriate. However, both cases would do the check, to avoid resulting in an invalid state.

Comment: Much appreciated! Yeah, I'm somewhat aware of that C# pattern, though I don't often see it in Java so it's not normally something I think about.